# How to implement GMSMapViewDelegate in class that extended from UIview?

Tags: ios, google-maps, swift3, cocoa-touch

I have multi target application that they have to use google map i decided to create cocoa touch framework and add all google map dependencies and create a nib to show google map.This work successfully and i can reuse that nib file in projects that embedded my framework and i can show user current location on map but i need to implement GMSMapViewDelegate to detect when map moves but when implement GMSMapViewDelegate i got below error :

ld: framework not found GoogleMaps for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

this is my nib file class

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

class GoogleMapView: UIView,MyLocationManagerDelegate,GMSMapViewDelegate {

    let marker = GMSMarker()

    @IBOutlet weak var geoCodeAddressTxtfield: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var mapView: GMSMapView!

    public var geoAddresshandler :((_ lat :CLLocationDegrees, _ long :CLLocationDegrees) -> Void)?

    private let nibName :String = "GoogleMapXib"
    let locationManager = MyLocationManager()

    public override init(frame : CGRect){
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        locationManager.delegate = self
        setup()
    }

    func getLocationCordination(long: CLLocationDegrees, lat: CLLocationDegrees) {
         let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: lat, longitude: long, zoom: 17)
        mapView.camera = camera
        mapView.animate(to: camera)
        mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
        let marker = GMSMarker()
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: long)
        marker.map = mapView
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapAt coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        print("You tapped at \(coordinate.latitude), \(coordinate.longitude)")
    }
    private func setup(){
        self.mapView = UINib(nibName: nibName, bundle: Bundle(for: type(of: self))).instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! GMSMapView
        self.mapView.frame = bounds
        self.mapView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth , .flexibleHeight]
        self.addSubview(self.mapView)
        self.geoCodeAddressTxtfield.becomeFirstResponder()
        mapView.bringSubview(toFront: self.geoCodeAddressTxtfield)
    }
    func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView!, didTapAtCoordinate coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, willMove gesture: Bool){
        mapView.hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()
    }
    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didChange position: GMSCameraPosition){}
}
```

Comment: Have you add your framework in Linked binary ?

Comment: yes and I can reuse this nib file in projects that used my framework